# Python Tkinter and Sqlite giving operational error but I followed a tutorial perfectly

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, tkinter

I'm new to TKinter and was trying out databases. I'm going with the rudimentary built in sql in python right now. It's quite simple. A window pops up asking name and address. The user inputs get put into a database after clicking <kbd>Add record</kbd> button and the inputs reset afterwards so more inputs can be added. I followed the tutorial perfectly but sqlite is giving some errors.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import sqlite3      # a lite sql comes built in with python

root = Tk()
root.title("Databases!!")
root.iconbitmap("D:/de_clutter/comdes/tkinter/images/__icon_test.ico")

conn1 = sqlite3.connect('address_data.db')

c = conn1.cursor()

def Submit():
    conn1 = sqlite3.connect('address_data.db')
    c = conn1.cursor()

    c.execute("INSERT INTO address VALUES(:f_name, :l_name, :address_name, :city_name, :state_name, :zipcode_name)",
              {
                  "f_name" : f_name.get(),
                  "l_name": l_name.get(),
                  "address_name": address_name.get(),
                  "city_name": city_name.get(),
                  "state_name": state_name.get(),
                  "zipcode_name": zipcode_name.get(),
              }
              )

    conn1.commit()
    conn1.close()

    f_name.delete(0, END)
    l_name.delete(0, END)
    address_name.delete(0, END)
    city_name.delete(0, END)
    state_name.delete(0, END)
    zipcode_name.delete(0, END)

f_name = Entry(root, width = 30)
f_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
l_name = Entry(root, width = 30)
l_name.grid(row=1, column = 1)
address_name = Entry(root, width = 30)
address_name.grid(row=2, column = 1)
city_name = Entry(root, width = 30)
city_name.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
state_name = Entry(root, width = 30)
state_name.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
zipcode_name = Entry(root, width = 30)
zipcode_name.grid(row = 5, column = 1)


f_name_label = Label(root, text = "Enter your first name")
f_name_label.grid(row=0, column = 0)
l_name_label = Label(root, text = "Enter your last name")
l_name_label.grid(row=1, column = 0)
address_name_label = Label(root, text = "Enter your address")
address_name_label.grid(row=2, column = 0)
city_name_label = Label(root, text = "Enter your city")
city_name_label.grid(row=3, column = 0)
state_name_label = Label(root, text = "Enter your state")
state_name_label.grid(row=4, column = 0)
zipcode_name_label = Label(root, text = "Enter your postal code")
zipcode_name_label.grid(row=5, column = 0)


submit_btn = Button(root, text = "Add record", command = Submit)
submit_btn.grid(row = 6, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

conn1.commit()

conn1.close()

root.mainloop()
```

the typing in entries work, but when I submit it I get this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Taief\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Taief\PycharmProjects\tKinter\venv\18_buildingoutguifordatabase.py", line 30, in Submit
    c.execute("INSERT INTO address1 VALUES(:f_name, :l_name, :address_name, :city_name, :state_name, :zipcode_name)",
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: address
```

I did exactly as the guy and we are on the same version. What's going on??

Comment: Did you create the table `address` inside `address_data.db`?

Comment: That error message doesn't make sense. `INSERT INTO address1` and `no such table: address`? The table name should be the same in both parts.